# How to test a solution to a memory leak on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, memory-leaks

I ran into a memory leak (I think) when I got a (Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)) and (end of file reached error) recently when i'm using sidekiq and loading a large set of Customers into a background worker process. Here's what I'm doing:

```
user.company.customers.subscribed.each do |customer|
```

and instead, I want to try loading this into batches to see if that fixes the issue. However, I'm not quite sure how to test the solution. Is the only way to create a staging environment and copy the database over? Seems like overkill to test this.

Answer (score 0):

You use the memory profiler and test with various batch sizes

https://github.com/ice799/memprof

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with adding the Librato metrics addon to your heroku application so you are able to monitor the memory usage. Heroku exports the current memory usage to the logs and librato parses and shows that in their graphs.

Then you can use find_each (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html) with smaller batch sizes and increase batch sizes (for example through an environment variable) to see how the memory behaves. Maybe the default of 1000 is even small enough but you can decrease to test.